# WordPress Query search by tags

Tags: wordpress

I am currently working on a project which is implemented in wordpress. I want to be able to search for custom post using tags.

I tried:

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'tag=' . $tag );
```

But no post get returned.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
<?php
 $args=array(
 'tag__in' => array(87),//replace with your tag id
 'post_type' => 'custom'//replace with your custom post type
  );
query_posts($args));
?>
```

Comment: Is this code portable? I see your suggested the use of tag id, will it work if I move the site from development environment to production or will I need to modify the files?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a custom post type then you have to add `post_type` parameter

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'your_custom_post_typy', 'tag' => $tag );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Also make sure that, you've used `'taxonomies'=>array('post_tag')` in `register_post_type`.